# How to add values to 2 table then map foreign key from one table to another table in Entity Framework Core using Postgresql?

Tags: c#, postgresql, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Here is another issue I have faced in ASP.NET Core
Let say I have 2 Tables:

```
Accommodation
( ID, Name, LocationID)
Location
(ID, Address, Latitude, Longitude)
```

And I have a form:

```
Name:
Address:
Latitude:
Longitude:
```

Then when a button is clicked I want the value to be updated on both table and also MAP the LocationID to Accommodation table
How should I code it in EF Core? Like a proper way

Answer (score 0):

You could try  the following example I made :

Accommodation Model and Location Model

```
 public class Accommodations
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int LocationID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("LocationID")]
    public Location Location { get; set; }
}
public class Location
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    //other stuff you want
}
```

DbSet two model in DbContext

```
 public class MVCDbContext:DbContext
{
    public MVCDbContext(DbContextOptions<MVCDbContext> options) : base(options)
    { }
    public DbSet<Accommodations> Accommodations { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Location> Location { get; set; }
}
```

The design of the view ,pay attention to the `asp-for` of the input tag

```
@model MVC2_1Test.Models.Accommodation.Accommodations
@{
ViewData["Title"] = "Accommondation";
}

<h2>Accommondation</h2>

<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4">
    <form id="form" class=".has-error" asp-action="CreateAccommodation">
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        <div class="form-group ">
            <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" id="cusName" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Location.Address" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="Location.Address" class="form-control" id="age" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Location.Address" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />

        </div>
    </form>
</div>
</div>
```

The action to update both table

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> CreateAccommodation([FromForm]Accommodations accommodation)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _context.Add(accommodation);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        return View(accommodation);
    }
```